# Beer has off flavor, sample taken while bottling tasted good

Tags: beer, off-flavor, dry-hop, ipa

I brewed an IPA about 3 weeks ago. Everything went fine during fermentation and I've dropped a couple of hop pellets 4 days before bottling into the fermenter as I planned to do.

When bottling everything went fine and I took a sample to measure the FG (with priming sugar, forgot to take it before).

I've put the sample into the fridge (after measuring the FG) and drank it after 3 days, it tasted good! I decided to put a couple of bottles into the fridge, and when taking them out of the closet they were in I saw the following "dust" swimming inside the beer (picture at the end of post).

When tasting the beer it lost its juicy taste that the sample had and it looks a bit darker. From my experience I would say it has this "old" IPA taste and sugary/caramel smell.

I've put the beer into a closet for 4 5 days once bottled, temperature was maybe a bit high (probably reached 80°F at some point).

My question is: Why did the sample tasted great and the actual beer not as good? Was the room temperature too high? Did I leave too much air in the bottles? Does it have anything to do with this "dust" in suspension?

Hope some of you can help me understand what I did wrong. My other all grain beers went fine but I didn't do any dry hop.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How old is it? I know from experience just a few days at warm temps like you described 80°F will make a delicate beer taste like it was age weeks.

Noticing the green bottles, light struck (skunking) can happen in a matter of minutes.  Even bottling in direct light using clear lines can do it in the short time it passes through the line.

Comment: 5 days old (4 days after bottling on the picture, poured it into a glass the next day). I also have a couple of brown bottles, and it tastes about the same :/. Probably the temperature, your experience kind of confirm that I guess... I usually don't worry about the room temp once bottled, I guess I should!

Comment: Heat will change it in a hurry. One experience was an IPA 12 pack, had them on ice we drank about 6 of them cold. By the end of the day the ice was gone beer was hot 90ish the leftovers I brought home and put in the cooler chilled to 38 and tasted like a dead 6 month old IPA all malt forward no hop luster. And that's just a few hours of heat.